# Can't Figure out how to While Loop in Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a 2D Shooter game in Unity and so far I have made a shooting system, but when I tried to make the gun full auto, I doesn't work, please help, I've only been doing Unity for 1.5 years so I'm still very new and I just Don't understand why it isn't working.
Code:

```
 private void Start()
{
    while (Input.GetButton("Fire1"))
    {
        Shoot();
        StartCoroutine(Delay());
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not the coroutine doesnt look like it will influence your shoot its not going to delay your code as you dont say if ok then shoot you shoot and run delay

Answer (score 8):

You don't need a while loop, that too in the `Start()` method. Input events are captured in `Update()` method, which runs every frame.

Reference: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetButton.html

```cs
private void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetButton("Fire1"))
    {
        Shoot();
        Startcoroutine(Delay());
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah this works but since its not looping the delay doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

To add on top of the other answer, it seems that you're not very familiar with Unity's game loop. So here are four basic methods that you might need to use on a `Monobehaviour` class.

**Awake**
is called when the script instance is being loaded. Unity calls Awake **only once** during the lifetime of the script instance. You should use this **instead of a constructor** for initialization.

**Start** is called on the frame just before any of the Update methods (that you will see below) are called the first time.

**Update** is where you put your code that you want to be executed **every frame**. The classic game loop.

**FixedUpdate** is where you put code related to **physics** (Rigidbody) and is called every **fixed frame**. Fixed frames are related to the **frequency** of the physics system, which is **frame-rate independent**.

More information about the execution order [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can use "while" in Coroutines. Then all you need to do **StartCoroutine** when you press "Fire1" and **StopCoroutine** when you press up

```
private IEnumerator Delay;

private void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
    {
        Delay = DelayCoroutine();
        StartCoroutine(Delay);
    }

    if (Input.GetButtonUp("Fire1"))
    {
        if (Delay != null)
        { StopCoroutine(Delay); }
    }
}

IEnumerator DelayCoroutine()
{
    while (true)
    {
        Shoot();
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Start` method is called only one time when you run the game, and it never calls again, so the while loop won't work in the `Start` method, instead , you have to put the while in `Update` method which is called every frame

Comment: this just crashes the  game because its shooting like 1 billion bullets a second

Comment: yeah you're right, I forgot to tell you that in the update Method, you don't need to use While loop , just use if statement, 
if(Input.GetMouseButton("Fire1").......
because Update Method loops already, so loop into loop equals crash